# Is it possible to get the new column size from a GridSizeEvent in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxgrid

When a `wx.grid.Grid`'s column is resized, a [`wx.grid.GridSizeEvent`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.GridSizeEvent-class.html) is emitted. From the docs and `dir(event)` output this appears to be the most useless class in all of wxPython. It apparently doesn't tell you *any* of the relevant information regarding a column resize: which column was resized, what size it had before and which size it has now.

I suppose I can maintain a dict of `{<column_index>: <column_size>}` pairs, then manually derive the relevant data from that on each resize event, but I assume I've missed something and that this won't be necessary, so:

**Is it possible to find out which column was resized from a `GridSizeEvent` without manually keeping track of all column sizes?**

Answer (score 0):

This class does have `GetRowOrCol()` accessor. As for the new size, I think you need to use `GetPosition() - actual-width-or-height` but I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: `GetRowOrCol()` just returns 0 if a row was resized and 1 if a column was resized, which is entirely unhelpful since I'm listening to `EVT_GRID_COL_SIZE`. `GetPosition()` just returns the position of the cursor at the time of the event, so I'm afraid I don't entirely understand what you mean by `GetPosition() - actual-width-or-height`.

Comment: Did you actually test that it always returned 0 or 1 or do you just suppose that it does? Because it's definitely supposed to return the index of the row or column being resized.

Comment: I'm assuming, because when I debugged the event handler after resizing column #7, `event.GetPosition()` returned 1. I will definitively give it another shot though, just to make sure.